# Append data from one file to another

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

So I have a script that creates a CSV file looking like this:

```
Timestamp,Latitude,Longitude,MinSeaLevelPressure,MaxIntensity
1800 UTC MAY 16,
0000 UTC MAY 17,
0600 UTC MAY 17,
1200 UTC MAY 17,
1800 UTC MAY 17,
0000 UTC MAY 18,
0600 UTC MAY 18,
1200 UTC MAY 18,
1800 UTC MAY 18,
0000 UTC MAY 19,
0600 UTC MAY 19,
1200 UTC MAY 19,
1800 UTC MAY 19,
0000 UTC MAY 20,
0600 UTC MAY 20,
1200 UTC MAY 20,
1800 UTC MAY 20,
0000 UTC MAY 21,
```

What I would like to do is edit my code so that I can add data from another file looking like the second image below and append it to the end of each line so it matches up.

```
28.0
28.9
29.6
30.3
31.0
31.9
33.1
34.4
35.5
36.2
36.8
37.0
36.9
36.2
35.5
34.6
33.7
32.8
```

My current code is here:

```
#! /bin/bash
inputFileString=$1
outputFileString=$2
touch "$2"
chmod 755 "$2"
echo "" > lat.txt
sed -i '1d' lat.txt
rm $2
test=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
echo "Converting $inputFileString -> $outputFileString ..."
echo "" >  $2
awk -F '[<>]' '/<lat>/ {print $3}' $1 >> lat.txt
grep -Eo '<dtg>.*</dtg>' $1 | cut -c 6-20  >> $2
sed -i 's/$/,/' $2
#awk '{print $0, "$variable"}' $2 >> $2
#awk -F '[<>]' '/<lon>/ {print $3}' $1 >> $2
sed -i '1d' $2
sed -i '1i Timestamp,Latitude,Longitude,MinSeaLevelPressure,MaxIntensity' $2
echo Done!
```

Just for reference my code takes in an input of a kml file and extracts specific data and uses that data to produce a csv file.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.

Comment: BTW, you're probably making this far more complicated than it needs to be.  KML is an XML format, so you can use an XML parsing tool (such as `xmlstartlet`) or XML parsing library for your preferred programming language (e.g. perl, python, whatever) to extract all the data fields you require and output them in CSV format.   Also BTW, your question is quite similar to another question from earlier today, also asking about extracting data from a KML file, you may find useful info there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/694397/extracting-sea-level-pressure-from-kml-using-shell

Comment: @cas So unfortunately I have to write this program in one script file using UNIX and not python but I can still look into using an XML parsing tool correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my @a = @*ARGS[0].IO.lines.skip; my @b = @*ARGS[1].IO.lines;
         "Timestamp,Latitude,Longitude,MinSeaLevelPressure,MaxIntensity".put; 
         .put for [Z] @a, @b;' ethan1.txt ethan2.txt
```

Sample Output:

```
Timestamp,Latitude,Longitude,MinSeaLevelPressure,MaxIntensity
1800 UTC MAY 16, 28.0
0000 UTC MAY 17, 28.9
0600 UTC MAY 17, 29.6
1200 UTC MAY 17, 30.3
1800 UTC MAY 17, 31.0
0000 UTC MAY 18, 31.9
0600 UTC MAY 18, 33.1
1200 UTC MAY 18, 34.4
1800 UTC MAY 18, 35.5
0000 UTC MAY 19, 36.2
0600 UTC MAY 19, 36.8
1200 UTC MAY 19, 37.0
1800 UTC MAY 19, 36.9
0000 UTC MAY 20, 36.2
0600 UTC MAY 20, 35.5
1200 UTC MAY 20, 34.6
1800 UTC MAY 20, 33.7
0000 UTC MAY 21, 32.8
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. The Timestamp file is read off the command line as `@*ARGS[0]` (the Timestamp header line is `skip`-ped and added back later). The numeric column is read off the command line as `@*ARGS[1]`.  Each file is converted to an `IO` object, broken into `lines` and stored as arrays `@a` and `@b`. Then `@a` and `@b` are `[Z]` zipped together element-wise and `put`.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/Z
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are expecting but I think `paste` is what you are looking for:

```bsh
sed '1s!^!\n!' another.txt | paste -d '\0' input.csv -
```

```
Timestamp,Latitude,Longitude,MinSeaLevelPressure,MaxIntensity
1800 UTC MAY 16,28.0
0000 UTC MAY 17,28.9
0600 UTC MAY 17,29.6
1200 UTC MAY 17,30.3
1800 UTC MAY 17,31.0
0000 UTC MAY 18,31.9
0600 UTC MAY 18,33.1
1200 UTC MAY 18,34.4
1800 UTC MAY 18,35.5
0000 UTC MAY 19,36.2
0600 UTC MAY 19,36.8
1200 UTC MAY 19,37.0
1800 UTC MAY 19,36.9
0000 UTC MAY 20,36.2
0600 UTC MAY 20,35.5
1200 UTC MAY 20,34.6
1800 UTC MAY 20,33.7
0000 UTC MAY 21,32.8
```

`input.csv` and `another.txt` is copied from your question description.

Comment: Using `\n` in the replacement pattern is undefined. GNU `sed` will insert a newline, most other `sed` will insert an `n`. If you simply want to insert an empty line at the beginning, better do `sed '1H;1x'`, that's more portable and easier to read.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CZoMku9.png Tested on BSD, GNU and busybox. I don't think it would be a problem for the majority.

BTW, my shell is fish.

Comment: @Philippos I am curious and would appreciate if you can tell me other `sed` implementations that don't do to work.

Comment: What is the BSD `sed` version you tested with? The manual https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1 clearly states »To specify a newline character in the replacement string, precede it with a backslash.« Same for OpenBSD and NetBSD. I'm pretty sure that this will not work with BSD `sed` on MacOS. Neither will it work on Solaris and HP-UX. It's simply no POSIX feature. Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42321/how-can-i-instruct-bsd-sed-to-interpret-escape-sequences-like-n-and-t

Comment: That's weird because as the image I gave shows that it works on MacOS, isn't the built-in sed on MacOS based on BSD?

Comment: @Philippos Here is the sed I use https://i.imgur.com/8N0jMS4.png

Answer (score 0):

Using any versions of echo, cat, and paste in any bourne-like shell:

```
$ { echo ""; cat file2; } | paste -d '' file1 -
Timestamp,Latitude,Longitude,MinSeaLevelPressure,MaxIntensity
1800 UTC MAY 16,28.0
0000 UTC MAY 17,28.9
0600 UTC MAY 17,29.6
1200 UTC MAY 17,30.3
1800 UTC MAY 17,31.0
0000 UTC MAY 18,31.9
0600 UTC MAY 18,33.1
1200 UTC MAY 18,34.4
1800 UTC MAY 18,35.5
0000 UTC MAY 19,36.2
0600 UTC MAY 19,36.8
1200 UTC MAY 19,37.0
1800 UTC MAY 19,36.9
0000 UTC MAY 20,36.2
0600 UTC MAY 20,35.5
1200 UTC MAY 20,34.6
1800 UTC MAY 20,33.7
0000 UTC MAY 21,32.8
```

Or using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{print} NR==FNR{a[NR-1]=$0; next} {print a[FNR] $0}' file1 file2
Timestamp,Latitude,Longitude,MinSeaLevelPressure,MaxIntensity
1800 UTC MAY 16,28.0
0000 UTC MAY 17,28.9
0600 UTC MAY 17,29.6
1200 UTC MAY 17,30.3
1800 UTC MAY 17,31.0
0000 UTC MAY 18,31.9
0600 UTC MAY 18,33.1
1200 UTC MAY 18,34.4
1800 UTC MAY 18,35.5
0000 UTC MAY 19,36.2
0600 UTC MAY 19,36.8
1200 UTC MAY 19,37.0
1800 UTC MAY 19,36.9
0000 UTC MAY 20,36.2
0600 UTC MAY 20,35.5
1200 UTC MAY 20,34.6
1800 UTC MAY 20,33.7
0000 UTC MAY 21,32.8
```